# Dovecot starting and running, but not listening on any port

Tags: linux, networking, email, dovecot, debian-wheezy

I'm in charge of a Debian GNU/Linux (Wheezy) DomU for the mail services of the company I work for.

Yesterday one hard drive that was used for this particular server died.

After installing Debian again, Dovecot decided to no longer listen on any ports (checked with `netstat -l`). Other services (like Postfix and MySQL) work without problems.

`dovecot -n`:

```
# 2.1.7: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.2.0-3-amd64 x86_64 Debian wheezy/sid ext3
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
first_valid_uid = 150
last_valid_uid = 150
mail_gid = mail
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_uid = vmail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  prefix = 
}
pass db {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = mail
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/private/mail.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/mail.key
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 25
}
```

UID 150 is vmail (I double checked file permissions). I didn't install Dovecot from source, but via apt from the official Debian US mirror. There are no messages concerning Dovecot in `/var/log/syslog except` for:

```
Oct 21 06:36:29 server dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.1.7 starting up (core dumps disabled)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

You're missing a `protocols` directive to tell Dovecot which protocols to serve.

An example:

```
protocols = imap imaps pop3 pop3s
```

Comment: On Debian there is a `!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol` setting. These protocols are enabled automatically by an installation of corresponding packages, `dovecot-pop3d` for example.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud Thank you very much for that comment. I was wondering, why systemd was listening on the port instead of dovecot. Turns out, I was in fact missing dovecot-imapd :)

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question with an equally old answer, but on Ubuntu and Debian installs there is `/usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/` directory that should contain `.protocol` files. These are separate packages that one can install outside of the main Dovecot install. As explained here on [the official Ubuntu page for Dovecot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot):

> The installation is extremely simple, just install the following packages:
>
> 1. dovecot-imapd
> 2. dovecot-pop3d
>
> For example, using apt-get:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
> ```

So I recommend that you just go ahead and install those packages like this:

```
sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
```

Pretty sure after you do that and then check the `/usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/` directory you will see some `.protocol` files in there. Just restart Dovecot after doing that and you should be good. And feel free to install other `.protocol` files as needed.

Comment: Good God! Is there no end to the insanity of Debian systems?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, to be fair, I started my sysadmin career mainly dealing with Ubuntu boxes and now I am on RedHat and CentOS and it drives me nuts how if I upgrade a package like Apache, file system permissions are always changed for things like log files—which I often need to make non-admin readable—so each distro has its own strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: ACLs solve that problem pretty neatly, most of the time. I've [run into that one before myself](https://serverfault.com/a/695554/126632).